# Juntar 2 variables tipo Int en una variable Java

Tags: java, variables, números-enteros

Intentando hacer un código en java, llegué a un punto donde necesito hacer lo siguiente:

**EJEMPLO**

```
public void Numeros()
{
    int Unidad = 2;
    int Decima = 3;
    int Numero;
    Numero = (Acá quiero que la decima y la unidad se junten);
}
```

**Lo que quiero decir**

Exactamente aquí

```
 Numero = (Acá quiero que la decima y la unidad se junten);
```

Quiero que la variable Numero contenga la Decima y la Unidad, osea que diga 32.

Si la la Variable Décima es 5 y la variable Unidad es 2, que la variable numero diga 52.

Y así hasta que uno quiera.

Espero haberme explicado bien.
Gracias!

Comment: Saludos. Convierte cada numero es `string` los concatenas en el orden deseado y le aplicas (a ese `string`) conversión a `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu resultado `Numero` es `int`, igual que las demás variables, lo mas simple seria multiplicar la variable `Decima` por 10 y luego sumarle `Unidad`.

Answer (score 0):

Hola con el código que te adjunto se puede hacer lo que pides. Usando las clases envoltorio. Un saludo espero que te sirva.

```
    String Unidad = "2";
    
    String Decima = Unidad.concat("3");
    
    int numero = Integer.parseInt(Decima);  
    
    System.out.println(numero);
```